#  Computing Quarters in months fr a given DATE PERIOD requires fine tuned solution

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to compute the no. of quarters in months(rounded to 2 decimals) fr a given DATE period.

```
Fr eg, 
DATE FORMAT:DD/MM/YYYY
START DATE = 1/3/2012
END DATE = 1/6/2012
No of quarters shld be = 3  

DATE FORMAT:YYYY-MM-DD
START DATE = 2012-09-05
END DATE = 2012-11-21
No of quarters shld be = 0.85
```

I hve written a script(google apps scripts) to compute the quarters computing fnctn, nd it works fine!
My script is crossing 1000 lines over, which has many harcoded/constants written inside it like hardcoding months,years to calculate leap years,..,..etc

So, can someone give me a better idea/suggestion/solution to improve/reduce my codings?
Or am i nt using the best concept to write my script?

NOTE: Scenario I used:

For getting the decimal value I calculated for each possibility. Which is like "more than one year" & "with in year". Inside this "within a year" I used "more than one month" & "within a month". If "more than one month" & "within a year" is satisfied, I checked the month duration with checking every month.

I just added my code [here](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/chockalingamr/file/quarters%20code.txt) for more clearance.

Comment: Even if you have 1000+ LOC it would be helpful if you could elaborate on the approach you're using.

Comment: As per your guidance i just added the Scenario I used and I attached my code too for your clearance in the above post. Please take a look at it. Please let me know, If you need more details. @m90

Comment: what's about `var noOfQuarters = ((new Date(2012, 11, 21)).getTime()-(new Date(2012, 9, 5)).getTime())/((365/4)*24*60*60*1000);`

Comment: otherwise you have to be aware that you use quarters of different duration as the first quarter of the year is significantly shorter due to the reduced length of February. A duration defined as a multiple of durations with a *variable* length is mathematically, ehm, somehow undefined :-)

Comment: @Taras Tnx a lot for your guidance, but i need the accurate o/p in the decimal, but in your calculation it takes 1 or 2 days extra to complete a quarter. when i use Mar 1->Jun 1, it gave 1 quarter, but this should give 1.01 quarters. wat i expected is when Mar 1->May 31, it should be 1 quarter

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work:

(year2 - year1)*4 + (month2 - month1)/3

If you use actual dates instead of strings, you can call getFullYear and getMonth to find the year and month of each date.

BTW, how does
    START DATE = 1/3/2012
    END DATE = 1/6/2012
    No of quarters shld be = 3
work? How is 3 days = 3 quarters?

Comment: The date is in the format of DD/MM/YYYY. I missed to mention the date format. I just updated in the post also. And also I need the calculation with the decimal value. Tnx.

Comment: Then I think Taras had the right answer. Either the formula is good enough, or you have to separate the date range by quarter to account for the different lengths of months.

Would Mar 1->Jun 1 not be 1 quarter?